# Solve $\int_0^1 \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{~d} x$,

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

$\int_0^1 \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{~d} x$

Can someone help with this integral?

I Tried Fubini but it doesnt work. i switched dx and dy then i integred over x and the solution was $y(e^{1/y}−1)$ but when i integrad now over dx then its chaos.
I do:
$ \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \int_0^1 \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{~d} y$
And then:
$\int_0^1 \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} x$ and this is equal to $y(e^{1/y}−1)$

Comment: How exactly did you employ Fubini's theorem?

Comment: i switched dx and dy then i integred over x and the solution was $y(e^{1/y}-1)$ but when i integrad now over dx then its chaos.

Comment: @ReneFischer Looks like you didn't adjust the limits of integration after changing the order.

Comment: How i adjust the limits?

Comment: Ok. But how can i correct it?

Comment: Oh yes. but i dont know if i need now Fubini or not?

Comment: Yes, Fubini is what you want  @AnneBauval's point is it gives you $\int_0^1\int_{y^2}^y\exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$, which you should find works out quite nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \int_0^1 \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{~d} y$ makes no sense. $x$
cannot be both a variable of integration and a parameter in the limits of the integral. You have to convert $0\le x\le1, x\le y\le\sqrt x$ into $0\le y\le1,y^2\le x\le y$.

[image]

Fubini-Tonelli theorem provides you the equality:
$$\int_0^1 \int_x^{\sqrt{x}} \exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} y \mathrm{~d} x=\int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^y\exp \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \mathrm{d} x\mathrm{~d} y,$$
which makes the integral quite easy to calculate.

Comment: I was considering posting an answer myself but I don't see much point in retreading the same ground. Do you mind if I insert a supplementary visual aide? (Not sure if that's proper CW etiquette)

Comment: [Please do!](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)